# Peashooter vs Bloomerang Plant Food

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

Recently I started playing *Plants vs. Zombies 2* and now I'm sometimes doubting if I should use **[Plant Food](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Plant_Food)** on *[Peashooters](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Peashooter)* or *[Bloomerangs](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Bloomerang)*.

When applied to a *[Peashooter](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Peashooter)*, it will force it to shoot like a *[Gatling Pea](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Gatling_Pea)* from *Plants vs. Zombies*, but ***MUCH*** faster for a short period of time.

When applied to a *[Bloomerang](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Bloomerang)*, it will force it to shoot in 4 directions(UP-DOWN-LEFT-RIGHT) with lots of bloomerangs for a short period of time.

Assuming I only need to get rid of zombies in 1 lane, which of these should I feed with **[Plant Food](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Plant_Food)**?

Comment: remember the bloomerang can hit multiple zombies per boomerang, the pea shooter shots only 1 hit zombie at a time, bloomerang wins hands down if there are multiple zombies in that lane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**From my game play observations:**

While each bloomerang can hit a target twice (when going forward and then backward), those two hits combined, deal about the same amount of damage as a single pea from Peashooters. Thus, each boomerang can be considered equivalent to one pea, but can hit up to 3 targets - so equivalent to 3 peas if you have 3 or more zombies in one lane.

**Plant Food:**

When overcharged with Plant Food, Peashooters shoot approximately 20 peas a second for 3 seconds, that is 60 peas in one direction.

Bloomerang shoots approximately 10 boomerangs in all 4 directions when overcharged. That is equivalent to 10 to 30 peas shot to EACH direction when you have 1 to 3 targets.

**In conclusion:**

Peashooter: 60 peas in one direction.

Bloomerang: up to 30 peas-equivalent in one direction (if you have 3 or more zombies), theoretical max is 120 peas-equivalent  in all four directions.

So without considering other situations such as grave stones in the way, or a really tough zombie in front protecting annoying zombies, it seems like you should feed a Peashooter for its maximum fire power.

Answer (score 2):

You should apply food on the peashooter. While the bloomerang does give you a larger killing radius you're only looking to defeat a single enemy in a single row. Ergo, you should apply food to the plant that specializes in a single lane....Peashooter.

Comment: *Assuming I only need to get rid of ****zombies**** in 1 lane*

Comment: @Novarg If you have multiple zombies the peashooter will work the best. Bloomerangs have wasted boomerangs.

Comment: I agree, while the Boomerang hits multiple targets, it seems underpowered compared to the Peashooter when Plant Food is applied. Also, once the front target is down, it will hit the next target and so on as long as it lasts.

Comment: a single bucket zombie can almost completely absorb all the shots from a fed pea shooter, where a boomerang can take that out and everything else in the lane.

Comment: @spartacus Really? The exact opposite has been my experience. If the Buckethead is otherwise unharmed, then yes it takes nearly all of a Peashooter with Plant Food to kill it, but I've yet to see a Boomerang with Plant Food kill a Buckethead at all. Most of the time it doesn't even completely knock the bucket off.

Comment: @tubedogg remember boomerangs only hit the first 3 zombies in the lane.  Also you have to wait for the return strike.